# Unable to read entire POST request body content formatted as application/json

Tags: java, jetty, http-post

I've been having an issue with Jetty processing `application/json` formatted request body data. Essentially, when the request body is processed by Jetty, the request data is cut off.

I have a relatively large POST body of around 74,000 bytes. As per some advice I found online, I instantiated a new context handler with the `setMaxFormContentSize` property set to a sufficiently large size of 500,000 bytes.

```
    ServletContextHandler handler = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/");
    handler.setMaxFormContentSize(500000);
```

However, this did not seem to work correctly. I also read online that this property might only work for form encoded data, not `application/json`, which is a strict requirement of our application.

Is there any way to circumvent this issue? Is there some special constraint class that I can subclass to allow the processing size to increase to at least 500KB?

Edit #1: I should add that I also tried to drop the size of the limit to 5 bytes to see if it would cut off more of the data in the payload. That also didn't working, which seems to imply that's definitely ignoring the property entirely.

Edit #2: Here is where I read the information from the request stream.

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        String json = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(req.getInputStream()));
        ....
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception in internal api forwarder", e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

This seems to a standard way of reading from a request stream. I also tried using a `BufferedReader` from `req.getReader()` with the same issue.

Vivek

Comment: Maybe the application server configuration is preventing large requests?

Comment: Are you running jetty embedded or jetty server ?

Comment: We're currently using Jetty embedded in another application

Comment: `setMaxFormContentSize(int)` only affects `multipart/form-data` formatted request content.  You have `application/json` so its not even remotely related.  There's nothing in Jetty that limits request body content outside of `multipart/form-data`.  Edit your question and add *how* you are reading the request data (that's the likely place where the issue is)

Comment: Joakim Erdelt, I've editing my question to show how I'm reading the request stream. I've tried several methods for reading from the stream but they are all producing the incorrect results. Do you have any insights for me?

Answer (score 1):

What is this `CharStreams` object?

It doesn't seem to know, or care, or honor the request character encoding. (Bad idea)

Suggest that you use the servlet [`request.getReader()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getReader--) instead of `request.getInputStream()` (which is really only designed for binary request body content)

Using `request.getReader()` will at the very least support your request character encoding properly.

Another bit of information you might want to look into is [`request.getContentLength()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getContentLength--) and verify that the request headers does indeed contain the size you are expecting.